# Prove that there exists n consecutive composite numbers

Tags: proof-verification, prime-numbers, proof-writing

I'm asked to prove that there exists n consecutive composite numbers. This is what I've come up with.

$$n! + 1 = (1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4 \cdot 5 \cdot \dotsc \cdot n) + 1 $$ is a prime number since it gives a remainder of 1 with division of all values below it.

Now, for each value following $n! + 1$ i.e $$\\n! + 2, \\n! + 3, \\n! + 4, \\n! + 5, \\\dots \\n + k$$

where $k \leq n$ we can easily divide by k since k is clearly both part of $n!$ and $k$.

E.g $$\frac{n! + 11}{11} = \frac{n!}{11} + 1$$

Is this a valid proof? Is there a more efficient way to do it?

Comment: It is false that $n!+1$ is prime, in general.

Comment: A better way to start would be with $(n+1)!+2$ to get $n$ consecutive ones.

Comment: Doesn't work for all n.  $5!=120$, but $5!+1=121=11^2$

Comment: Despite the false claim that $n!+1$ is prime (as shown it is not always going to be), you are correct in recognizing that $n!+2,n!+3,\dots n^!+n$ are all composite numbers and therefore not prime.

Answer (score 2):

You have a good idea, don't ruin it by doing wrong statements like “$n!+1$ is prime”.

---

Indeed, $n!+k$ is divisible by $k$ for $2\le k\le n$, but this gives just $n-1$ consecutive composite numbers. However, there are $n$ if you consider $(n+1)!+k$, for $2\le k\le n+1$.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a good proof to me - the only issue is that $n!+1$ isn't always prime. That doesn't matter for the actual proof though, so you can remove it.

Answer (score 0):

No, $n!+1$ is not always prime.  It is not divisible by integers $\le n$, but it can have factors larger than $n$.  For example, $4!+1=25$ is not prime.
See [OEIS sequence A002981](https://oeis.org/A002981).